# Cannot install sqlsrv library for php5.6 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, ubuntu-14.04, unixodbc

How do I install this library to connect to mssql 2012 using my php5.6?

**UPDATE:**
 I have found that version 3.0.1 is the right version (correct me if I am wrong).

But now, I get this error:

```
pecl install sqlsrv-3.0.1    
downloading sqlsrv-3.0.1.tgz ...
Starting to download sqlsrv-3.0.1.tgz (134,966 bytes)
.............................done: 134,966 bytes
17 source files, building
running: phpize
Cannot find config.m4.
Make sure that you run '/usr/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module

ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

**UPDATE:**
When I try to manually install the file, the top level directory does not contain config.m4. It only contains config.w32... What do I do?

Comment: Would update as the error message describes? FWIW: https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases

Answer (score 1):

Get same problem on CentOS 7. File config.m4 don't exist in archive(version 3.0.1, in 4.0.4 file exist, but require php7.0 minimum) from pecl.php.net. I think this module don't work with linux php 5 versions. Better to compile mssql module.

That why i download full php archive from https://museum.php.net (in my case this was - php-5.6.40.tar.xz) and compile mssql from it

```
cd /tmp/
wget https://museum.php.net/php5/php-5.6.40.tar.gz
tar xvf php-5.6.40.tar.gz
cd php-5.6.40/ext/mssql/
/opt/php56/bin/phpize (in your case path to php5.6 phpize can be different)
yum install autoconf (on ubuntu package can have different name)
yum install freetds freetds-devel freetds-libs freetds (required to compile)
ln -s /usr/lib64/libsybdb.so /usr/lib/libsybdb.so (compiling search for libsybdb.so in /usr/lib/libsybdb.so but file was in  /usr/lib64/libsybdb.so that why i create symlink)
./configure --with-php-config=/opt/php56/bin/php-config (in your case path to php5.6 php-config can be different)
make
```

and i get mssql module with my php5.6 configuration

```
/tmp/php-5.6.40/ext/mssql/modules/mssql.so
```

and can easily connect it to my php56 in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

You can install a specific version like this: `pecl install sqlsrv-4.3.0`

You'll have to browse the changelogs [here](http://pecl.php.net/package/sqlsrv) to find what version you need.

Comment: I tried. But It doesnt specify? Will version 3 work for php5.6 ?

Comment: Sorry, no idea, you're going to need to figure that out yourself. You might just start at the top of the list and keep going down until one works.

Comment: Thanks, I found the version.

Comment: can you please update your comment with the version that worked for you?